# shopping cart - only update 1 entry

Tags: php, shopping-cart

The code below will only update the last entry of my cart. I'm struggling a bit with the loops and I'm just stuck.

```
 if (isset($_POST['quantity'])) { // Update quantities in the cart

    foreach ($_POST['quantity'] as $k => $qty) {  //Full name on form: name="quantity[' . $row['prodid'] . ']"

        $pid = $_POST ['prodid'];
        $sp_type = $_POST ['cat'];

        if (isset($sp_type, $pid)) {
             // Determine the quantity:
             $qty = (filter_var($qty, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 0)) !== false) ? $qty : 1;

             // Update the quantity in the cart:
             $r = mysqli_query($dbc, "CALL update_cart('$uid', '$sp_type', $pid, $qty)");
        }

    } // End of FOREACH 
}
```

Code on cart.html:

this is the code for the html form for the cart:

```
<input type="hidden" name="prodid[' . $row['prodid'] . ']" value="' .$row ['prodid'] .'" /></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="text" name="quantity[' . $row['prodid'] . ']" value="' . $row['quantity'] . '" size="2" class="small" /></td>
        <td align="right">£' . $price . '</td>
        <td align="right">£' . number_format($subtotal, 2) . '</td>
        <td align="right"><a href="/wishlist.php?id=' . $row['prodid'] . '&action=move&qty=' . $row['quantity'] .'&cat=' .$row ['cat_id'] .'">
```

Comment: You have a loop on quantity but not the prodid, I'd rearrange my form elements names better to suit looping. eg something along the lines of: name="quantity[$prodid]" so the key of that quantity becomes the product id

Comment: Can you provide a var_dump of your $_POST params?

Comment: how exactly do i do that?? Sorry, i'm a beginer (self taught).

Comment: just at a glance i bet you're not naming the input as arrays. example: <input type="hidden" name="prodid[]" value="<?php echo $some_id">

Comment: I have the 2 inputs (hidden) in the cart form 1: "prodid" and 2: "cat" for category. prodid is the product id. You may have a point there, the names above are without any id e.g. name="prodid" not name"prodid[]"

Comment: try to put an id to prodid and cat but i don't know how to modify the code above to read each!!

Answer (score 0):

After adding ID to all the inputs in the form.
I added the following to the code above and it works!!

```
        foreach ($_POST['prodid'] as $id=>$prod){
            if ($id==$k){
                $pid = $prod;
            }
        }
        foreach ($_POST['cat'] as $catid=>$cat){
            if ($catid==$k){
                $sp_type = $cat;
            }
        }
```

rest of code...